# Cell padding within inline CSS

Tags: css

I have a table within a div (see below).  How do I add a right padding of say 30px to each cell/column within the table in that div?  My understanding is that I have to use inline CSS?  Basically, I want each cell to be padded on the right by 30 pixels.

```
<div id="ddTopMenu";>
<table border="0" >
  <tr>
   <td width=100></td><td >Dictionary</td><td>Search</td><td>Sources</td><td>References</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll want to remove that `;` from the end of your `<div>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div#ddTopMenu table td {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: This solution not answers the question: "Cell padding within inline CSS". inline ok? Not in style. I came here because I searched on google cell padding inline css.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to select the dom element starting from 'ddTopMenu':

```
#ddTopMenu table td {
     padding: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you truly mean padding, which is like a margin within the TDs themselves, or a 30px separation between cells in the same row?

If you want a padding, then set the `padding-right` to 30px, possibly excepting the TDs in the last column.

If you want a 30px separation between cells in the same row, then you should take a look at [`border-collapse`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_tab_border-collapse.asp). Set the left and right border widths of all TDs to 30px, the border color to the background color of `#ddTopMenu`, and `border-collapse` to `collapse`. You can also set the right and left border widths of the rightmost and leftmost cells, respectively, to 0 so that the 30px separation is only between cells:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#ddTopMenu {
    display: inline-block;
    border: black 1px solid;
    background-color: red;
}

#ddTopMenu td {
    background-color: white;
    border-left: red 30px solid;
    border-right: red 30px solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

#ddTopMenu td.first {
    border-left-width: 0;
}

#ddTopMenu td.last {
    border-right-width: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="ddTopMenu">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
   <td width="100" class="first"></td><td >Dictionary</td><td>Search</td><td>Sources</td><td class="last">References</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```